# How to encrypt the data without exceed size of original data?

Tags: c#, encryption

My question is simple I am expecting encryption algorithm,

I need to encrypt a original data(text etc.) that encrypted data size should be same size of original data size? 
Share your idea kindly?

Example:
Original data is "test" (so length of text is 4) the expected encrypted data should be like this "etst" (so length is 4).

Comment: the result will not be serious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not always possible, especially with short amounts of data.  I am pretty sure that all the standard algorithms work on "blocks", which are usually the length of the key.  So unless you go with a really weak key, or use something weak like substitution cipher or caesar cipher your encrypted data could end up a little longer than the original.

Actually, according to [this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20120904015607/http://www.obviex.com/Articles/CiphertextSize.aspx) you can use a stream cipher and get encrypted text that is the same size as the input.  The example given is RC4.

Comment: What I understand from your answer is that for a secure encryption, if a "block" is of length N, the length of the ciphertext of a plaintext of length L will be N if L <= N, else ceiling((double)L/N)?

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using a plain substitution cypher, (replacing a letter with a different letter or symbol), you are looking at having a file that increases in size.  If you go with a substitution cypher those are extremely easy to break.  Why do you NEED to keep the file the same size?

Comment: Just i try to encrypt 10 MB file after its output may be 20 or 30 MB, that's why!

Comment: Are you writing or own algorithm or using an existing tool?  We use PGP to encrypt an send files on a regular basis and have not found it to be daunting in terms of size.  I would suggest that you try an existing tool/SDK if you have not already.

Answer (score 0):

Most encryption algorithms work on blocks of data. AES, for example, works on blocks of 128bit or 16 bytes. If you overflow a block by even 1 byte, AES must require another block worth of data.

with AES, you will always have a result that is a multiple of 16bytes.

If you resulting data is much larger, you should make sure you're feeding in a byte stream. If you, for some reason, copy in a file as text, .Net will convert it to Unicode which will change your data from 8bits per char to 16bit per char which will double the size of the output.